# LayerMask | Unity 2018.3f

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
if (movement != Vector3.zero)
    {
        LayerMask myMask = 1 << 8;
        if (!Physics.Raycast(this.transform.position + Vector3.up, transform.forward, 1f))
        {
            _playerAnimator.SetBool("Walk", true);
        }
        else
        {
            _playerAnimator.SetBool("Walk", false);
        }
        _playerRigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + movement);
        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(movement.normalized), 4 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    else
    {
        _playerAnimator.SetBool("Walk", false);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу, чтобы этот Raycast не реагировал на триггеры. Для этого я создал отдельный слой (N9). Здесь все вроде нормально и синтаксис не нарушен, но тем не менее объект, который использует этот скрипт вообще ни на что не реагирует. Можете помочь, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте проще, заведите у себя в компоненте `public` переменную `LayerMask`, и используйте сравнение с уже настроенной через редактор переменной. Прописывать в коде номер маски не гуд. Если вам в последствии потребуется заменить слой или сделать более сложную маску из комбинации нескольких слоев, вы просто сделаете настройку через редактор не правя кода.

Answer (score 1):

Маску вы может и задали (кстати, задали вы ее неверно), а где вы ее используете?

```
LayerMask myMask = 1 << 8;
if (!Physics.Raycast(this.transform.position + Vector3.up, transform.forward, 1f, ?где маска?))
{
    ...
}
```

---

Чтобы игнорировать 9 слой, нужно задать маску вот так:
LayerMask myMask = !(1 << 9);

1. `1 << 9 -> 10_0000_0000` - маска указывает только на 9й слой
2. `~(1 << 9) -> 01_1111_1111` - маска указывает на все слои, кроме 9го

Чтобы рейкаст учитывал маску, а не использовал дефолтную, пишем:

```
LayerMask myMask = ~(1 << 9);
if (!Physics.Raycast(this.transform.position + Vector3.up, transform.forward, 1f, myMask))
{
    ...
}
```

---

А вообще для таких случаев в рейкасте есть специальный параметр [`QueryTriggerInteraction`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/QueryTriggerInteraction.html), который позволяет игнорировать вообще любые триггеры:

```
Physics.Raycast(
    this.transform.position + Vector3.up,
    transform.forward,
    1f,
    Physics.DefaultRaycastLayers,
    QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore
)
```

Comment: LayerMask myMask = !(1 << 8); 
Rider подчеркиввает эту строку, пишет что ! не применимо к int.

Comment: @AndrewK. Моя ошибка, исправил ответ

Comment: Хммм... странно, все еще не работает. По прежнему учитывает триггер.

Comment: @AndrewK., а вы повесили хоть на объект с триггером 9й слой?

Comment: Да, конечно, сразу же проверил.

Comment: @AndrewK. дополнил ответ